# Find $n$th Term of the Sequence $1,2,3,8,13,30,55,\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, divergent-series

> Find $n$th Term of the Sequence $1,2,3,8,13,30,55,\dotsc$

Source: *Higher Algebra* by Bernald and Child

I tried using Successive differences which are
$1,1,5,5,17,25,\dotsc$ wherein I do not see any pattern.

Comment: This question has  no answer in  Mathematics. It is a question in mind reading and it is not suitable for this site.

Comment: Some entries at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=+1%2C2%2C3%2C8%2C13%2C30%2C55)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: this is a pretty negative standpoint. Such quizzes are a source of creative thinking. They have solutions in the sense of the Minimum Description Length, once you specify the allowed expressions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In recent times I have seen over a dozen such questions deleted on MSE. Saying that a few terms of  a sequence  determine the remaining  terms makes  a joke out of Mathematics.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: that's right. Also many claim that it suffices to fit a Lagrangian polynomial. It is a pity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers *seem* to obey the recurence relation
$$a_n=3a_{n-2}+2a_{n-3} \qquad \text{with}\qquad a_0=0, \quad a_1=1, \quad a_2=2$$ If this is the case, the characteristic equation is
$r^3=2r+3$ the roots of which being $(-1,-1,2)$ making the general solution to be
$$a_n=c_1(-1)^n+c_2(-1)^n n+c_3 2^n$$ Using $(a_0,a_1,a_2)$, just compute $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$.

Comment: Excellent. Why can't the Recurrence relation be $a_n=-2a_{n-1}+7a_{n-2}$, in that case i get the characteristic roots as $2\sqrt{2}-1$ and $-2\sqrt{2}-1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The pairwise *sums* are

$$3,5,11,21,43,85\cdots$$ which are the thirds of

$$9,15,33,63,129,255\cdots=8+1,15-1,32+1,64-1,128+1,256-1,\cdots$$

Hence

$$s_n=\frac{2^{n+2}-(-1)^n}3.$$

Comment: @WillJagy: I don't thank you.